# Remove garbage characters from grunt output

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

When running grunt in my jenkins job, these unknown characters appear in the output log.

Are there control characters for color?
I'm running grunt with --no-color

How do I get rid of these or have them display?

Execution Time (2015-01-26 21:01:15 UTC)
concurrent:dist     5.2s  ������������������������ 19%
autoprefixer:dist  532ms  ��� 2%
ngAnnotate:dist     2.1s  ������������ 7%
cdnify:dist         4.1s  ��������������������� 15%
uglify:generated   15.5s  ������������������������������������������������������������������������ 55%
Total 28s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unicode characters are actually just a representation of percentage and are supposed to render as Solid blocks as below.

```
Execution Time (2015-02-04 12:10:07 UTC)
loading tasks  139ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 4%
test:server     62ms  ▇▇▇▇ 2%
env:test       397ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 12%
mochaTest:src   2.6s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 81%
Total 3.2s
```

This comes from a plug-in called "time-grunt" which will be in your Gruntfile.js with:

```
require('time-grunt')(grunt);
```

Simply remove this and you shouldn't see them.

Only problem is you won't see the execution times anymore. I have been unable to find out how to support this...on a standard console you can just set encoding (LANG) to UTF-8, but I can't find out how to do this in Jenkins.

Comment: Ah..  Does this work for you? export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: Also, could there be a way to disable this on jenkins but allow it to run on local builds?

Comment: Okay so I did manage to resolve it by passing a JVM variable to Tomcat, much like your suggestion. I put this in catalina.sh :

    export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

I assume your export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS didn't work?

Regarding your second question...I'm not sure. The only way I could think of is if your local builds are done on Windows? Then you could check environment variable.